# Format curly braces on new lines when press enterkey in C++ VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, braces

I have these option enabled in settings.json

```
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.lambdaBracesWhenParameter": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.withinInitializerListBraces": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.scopeBracesOnSeparateLines": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeInitializerListOpenBrace": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeLambdaOpenParenthesis": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeOpenSquareBracket": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.block": "newLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.lambda": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.namespace": "newLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.type": "newLine",
"C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.closeBraceSameLine.emptyFunction": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.closeBraceSameLine.emptyType": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeEmptySquareBrackets": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.wrap.preserveBlocks": "allOneLineScopes",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.pointerReferenceAlignment": "right",
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Enabled",
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Visual Studio",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.function": "newLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.caseContents": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.namespaceContents": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.caseLabels": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.removeBeforeSemicolon": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.insertAfterSemicolon": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.caseContentsWhenBlock": true,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.afterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": false,
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.space.beforeBlockOpenBrace": false
```

If i write

```
if(/*some instruction*/){}
```

and if cursor is between {} and press enter i obtain this

```
  if(/*some instruction*/)  
{
    
  }
```

What i want is this

```
  if(/*some instruction*/)
  {

  }
```

I don't find where are settings to get it.

Comment: try to add ```"editor.formatOnType": true``` to your settings.json

Comment: i added but same problem

Comment: maybe try to format your code by clang-format option. You may use [this one](https://github.com/zanaviska/defaults/blob/c%2B%2B/.clang-format). According to [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting) to use this option just locate **.clang-format** file in your root dir

Comment: It's always the same if i press enter key the opening brace goes to a new line but it isn't indented